# SET WMIC in BATCH to make use of program versions

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to parse a wmic result to a variable in a batch file, but it seems as if I am trapped in the escape sequences of the strings I use...

The variable pver, should contain my version number at the end of this line in a batch file. But I am not getting the right syntax.

The folder \App is just an example, same as the file name of the application.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('wmic datafile where "Name=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\name.exe" get version') do set pver=%a
```

anyone an Idea were I made my mistake in thinking?

Comment: you claim using the code `in a batch file`, but you use command line syntax. In a batchfile change each `%a` to `%%a`.

Comment: I would try to get the `wmic` command line working before wrapping `for /F` around...

Answer (score 1):

```
set "pver="&for /F "tokens=2delims==" %a in ('wmic datafile where "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\visipics\\visipics.exe'" get version /format:list') do @if not defined pver set "pver=%a"
```

worked for me from the prompt. Apparently, the filename needs to be single-quoted. The `format` option produces a line of the format `version=value` which can be parsed by a for/f

Answer (score 1):

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC DataFile Where "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\name.exe'" Get Version`) Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~A") Do @Set "pver=%%B"
```

Or over shorter lines:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC DataFile Where^
 "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\name.exe'" Get Version
`) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~A") Do Set "pver=%%B"
```

From the command line:

```dos
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %A In (`WMIC DataFile Where "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\name.exe'" Get Version`) Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %B In ("%~A") Do @Set "pver=%B"
```

In both cases, note that WMIC will trailing pad the output with fixed width spaces. You may need to deal with them afterwards.

Like this perhaps:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC DataFile Where^
 "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\App\\name.exe'" Get Version
`) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%~A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Echo %pver%
Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "pver=%*"
```

Comment: What makes the third line of the `WMIC` output disappear?

Comment: The second `For` loop is there just for that very purpose.